# why I can't use encode_plus properly

Tags: huggingface-transformers

Here is my code:

```py
segment_a = "food anecdotes service ambience or price?"
label_names = ['food', 'anecdotes', 'service', 'ambience', 'price']
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
sentences = ["I am sad! I can't fix this bug!"]
for x in sentences:
    x = tokenizer.encode_plus(segment_a, x)
    input_id = x['input_ids']
    print(tokenizer.convert_ids_to_tokens(input_id))
```

then output is

```py
['[CLS]', 'food', 'an', '##ec', '##dote', '##s', 'service', 'am', '##bie', '##nce', 'or', 'price', '?', '[SEP]', 'i', 'am', 'sad', '!', 'i', 'can', "'", 't', 'fix', 'this', 'bug', '!', '[SEP]']
```

I don't understand why I am getting the subwords `['food', 'an', '##ec', '##dote', '##s', 'service', 'am', '##bie', '##nce', 'or', 'price', '?']`.
My expectation is that it should be split like `['food', 'anecdotes', 'service', 'ambience', 'price']`.
Does anybody know about it? I would appreciate it if you could help me!!

Comment: you are currently not passing label_names to the tokenizer? Can you explain in more detail *why* you expect the splitting to be respected?

Comment: I got the answer! Because this bert tokenizer will split every words that not in vocab

Comment: Well done! If you have an answer, please take the time to post a more extensive one below; you can also write/accept your own answers, and this way help people with similar problems in the future :)